# popen3 hangs when executing script with popen3

Tags: ruby, bash, output, deadlock

I have next code

```
 def execute_bash(cmd)
  puts "Executing: [#{cmd}]"
  exit_code = Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    stdin.close
    stdout.each { |line| puts line }
    stdout.close
    stderr.each { |line| puts line }
    stderr.close
    wait_thr.value.exitstatus
  end
  return exit_code
end
```

Command that I run with this function is vagrant up, that produces a lot of output. I have a lot of recipes so I need to monitor it's output in realtime, line by line.

And I have another script that ensures that previous script did well and did not crash. So I have another script that runs bash commands in the same way as previous. So I'm like running(in second script):

```
execute_bash "./vagrant_up.rb"
```

Such consequence leads me to dead lock or something: in some point output  stops. I could wait a lot of time but it will not continues.

When I run just vagrant in console - everything is fine.

Is that a problem to run ruby script with popen3 in another popen3?
Is there proper way of handling dead locks in popen3(if it's dead lock, I'm not sure)?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what the real issue is without seeing the details of vagrant_up.rb but consider the following.

Here I have a little bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#out.sh
echo "about to sleep"
sleep 3
echo "just woke up"
```

And another:

```
#!/bin/sh
#err.sh
echo "about to sleep" 1>&2
sleep 3
echo "just woke up" 1>&2
```

With your code, running `execute_bash("out.sh")` produces something that is probably in line with your expectations. It says "about to sleep" and then 3 seconds later it says "just woke up". But, running `execute_bash("err.sh")` does something a little surprising. It waits 3 seconds then prints "about to sleep" and "just woke up".

So, for your situation, here is my guess. Your command is probably producing a lot of output to stderr, and you just aren't seeing it. In fact you won't see it until the command finishes (because the stdout stream for the Open3 process won't be closed until then).

Can you just redirect stderr to stdout? Can you comment if this doesn't resolve the issue?

```
execute_bash("./vagrant_up.rb 2>&1")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, redirecting stderr did not help. Could same deadlocks happen with system() function?